# How many delimit we can use in ng-app?

Tags: angularjs, ng-app

Most of them angularjs developer are using ng-app, but we can use ng_app also.
any other delimit use in the ng-app ??

Comment: I think this question is more google specific rather Stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

I got another delimiter using in ng app

ng:app is also works